# MVC .NET application start logged out

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, authentication, authorize

I've made an application with .NET MVC and I have one bug that I can't seem to solve.

When I start my application and you're still loggedin from the last time you will appear to be logged in, however when you click on a page lets say "Admin Dashboard" (which requires you to be logged in) it keeps loading and it shuts down with a timeout error.

If I log out and back in it works perfectly fine.

How can I make it so that when you start the application you're ALWAYS logged out? :)

Thanks in advance.

Using .NET Entity Framework 5.0.0

EDIT: I've tried persistcookie: false but that didnt work.. I'm still logged in after restarting the mvc application.
 The code for my login actionresult in accountcontroller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            if (returnUrl == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect(Server.UrlDecode(returnUrl));
            }

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call

```
WebSecurity.Login
```

method set `persistCookie = false`

Though you should not have to do this..but without actual code I can only give answer to your question.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.. im still logged in after I restart the application and it still doesnt let me get to the authorized pages. Only when I log out and back in it works. (Added some code) what code would you like to see?

Comment: @ConsoleeLogg if it doesn't work then its probably your browser's problem. The cookie should get deleted once you close your browser

Comment: You are right! I've tried it in a different browser and it works! I will put you're answer as accepted! Do you maybe have an idea why it could be bad to be still logged in?

Comment: @ConsoleeLogg that I have absolutely no idea. HTTP is suppose to be stateless so stay logged in shouldn't effect anything.